# Discerning between two different linear regression models in one sample

Tags: regression, classification, data-mining, mixture-distribution

Suppose I observe a sample $(y_i,x_i)$, $i=1,...,n$. Suppose that I know the following:

$y_i=\alpha_0+\alpha_1x_i+\varepsilon_i$, $i \in J\subset\{1,...,n\}$

$y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1x_i+\varepsilon_i$, $i \in J^c$

where $\varepsilon_i$ are i. i. d. and $J$ is not known in advance. Is it possible to estimate $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\beta_0,\beta_1$? Or at least test the hypothesis that $J=\varnothing$?

If $J$ is known the problem is very easy to solve. Going through all the subsets is not feasible, since we have $2^n$ possible combinations. If we assume $J=\{1,...,k\}$ with unknown $k=1,...,n$, it is the classical change-point problem, for which many tests are available. I suspect that this maybe ill-posed problem, so I wanted to check before trying to solve it.

Here is a simple illustration of the problem:

```
N <- 200
s1 <- sample(1:N,N %/% 2)
s2 <- (1:N)[!(1:N) %in% s1]

x <- rnorm(N)
eps <- rnorm(N)

ind <- 1:N

y <- rep(NA,N*T)
y[ind %in% s1] <- 2+0.5*x[ind %in% s1]+eps[ind %in% s1]/5
y[ind %in% s2] <- 1+1*x[ind %in% s2]+eps[ind %in% s2]/5
y

sal1 <- ind %in% s1

plot(x, y)
points(x[sal1], y[sal1], col=2)
abline(2, 0.5, col=2)
abline(1, 1)
```

Graphically it is more or less obvious that we have two different models. Maybe it is possible to use some classification or data-mining techniques for solving this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to model the observations as a mixture model. Define:

$p$ as the probability that a sample belongs to the first data generating process.

Thus, the density function of $y_i$ is given by:

$f(y_i|-) \sim p f_1(y_i|-) + (1-p) f_2(y_i|-)$

where

$f_1(.)$ is the density that arises because of the first data generating process and

$f_2(.)$ is the density that arises because of the second data generating process.

You can then either use maximum likelihood (see for example the [EM algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation-maximization_algorithm)) or bayesian approaches to estimate the model.

Comment: Yes, mixture models are exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

The first hit on [Rseek](http://Rseek.org) with keywords "mixture regression" brings up the `flexmix` package, which does what you want. I seem to recall that there were other packages for this as well.

Comment: For now flexmix is working very nicely, thank you very much for the hint